# What do you call a woman who's feeling "emotional"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang, political-correctness

It's that time of the month, your female partner has begun to fault pick you, for no explicable reason she becomes weepy, and anything you say or do will be criticized or misinterpreted.

Is there a word or expression for your partner or girlfriend or her behaviour?
What do you call a person who's feeling "*bitchy*" (note the *scare quotes*) due to their mood swings?

Please, no vulgar, crude expressions. That would be taking the easy way out, what's more I already know those terms.

Thank you!

Comment: PMS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premenstrual_syndrome

Comment: @skymninge so you would call your GF or wife a *PMS*? How would you *phrase* it?

Comment: No, I would call the state a PMS, but I have known men who use it as synonym for the behaviour in general as well. Although, it was humorous I guess. I was the cranky one. ;-)

Comment: Emotional? Moody? Luckily my lady doesn't get particularly emotional at that time of month, so I don't need to use any special tactics.

Comment: I've heard PMS used as a verb, too: “She's PMS-ing”.

Comment: I'd think "My wife"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, In my experience "PMSing" is used by a woman to describe *herself*. If used by a second party, it's intended to be both slightly catty and exculpatory ("What's up with *her*?" // "Oh, don't worry about it, she's just PMSing").

Comment: @DanBron Thats exactly the use I had in mind. All a matter of tone, of course. "Oh, poor you, are you PMSing (or even PMSy) again?" is not generally offensive (to me).

Comment: I think some (myself being one) find it hard that a question is being asked for a term to describe a *woman* who behaves in a particular way when that cluster of behaviours is exhibited by men and women. There seems to be a gender stereotype assumed in the question which feels wrong especially as such stereotypes can be so destructive. I suspect many people won't see this (and I haven't downvoted the question for that reason) but if you asked me this question in my social group I *would* call you out on it.

Comment: @FrancisDavey thank you for your comment. Never would I have thought that my question could be perceived as being potentially harmful or disrespectful to anyone, least of all toward my gender. Thankfully, the vast majority of the answers posted have responded in the right spirit, and I have laughed heartily along with them as I am a great believer in not taking oneself too seriously. But I promise I will be more sensitive in the future. In the meantime, I have learnt new *cranky* expressions, and "re-learnt" expressions long forgotten, which was the *only* innocent aim of my question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - no criticism intended of you. It may be cultural or contextual. I ran it past my wife and she broadly agreed with me - but maybe we live in a different place. Exchanging views on this kind of thing can only help.

Comment: "Overly sensitive"?  "Touchy"?

Comment: It's too late for me to change my question and ask *"What do you call your partner when he or she is irritable?"* That would be unfair to the users who have posted, it's too drastic an edit and it's a different question. Besides I wanted to know what to call someone or their behaviour when they experience these mood swings. Maybe *that question* would have caused fewer people to take umbrage. But please note the quality and tone of the answers that have been posted. None are disrespectful, and many are light-hearted in nature.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's too late in the day to change the question without invalidating several answers at the same time. I'm stumped as to finding a way round this.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it is very difficult to deal with different sensibilities...but I think you have shonw your respect for all possible diverging views on the subject!!

Comment: Seems a reasonable question about language usage, regardless of the fact that the concept one wants to express could be offensive. There are *extremely* offensive terms for "a woman has a lot of sex" or "a woman who doesn't want to have sex with me", and it's somewhat offensive to judge people in those terms regardless of the term you use. But one still might want to know a range of more and less offensive ways of expressing an observation. I wonder whether some questions on the site could avoid controversy with, "I'm writing this fictional character..." ;-)

Comment: Don't call her anything .. it will be wrong whatever you say!!

Comment: @SteveJessop I think I'll use that stratagem the next time. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: "What do you call a person..." Unless you have a death wish, you don't call her anything. If you value your life and relationship more than clever wording, you ask no questions and just empathise with how she feels, patiently.

Comment: I like the top four answers the best; oerkelens, heyzeuss, myol and dnagirl each for a different reason. I cannot decide...

Comment: I have decided. The seventh downvote and the tenth upvote for Francis Davey's considerate comment has swayed me, finally. Thank you 7th downvoter for convincing me that my question is, above all, **a legitimate language** one.

Comment: Was the question supposed to say no *rude* expressions? Something you can say to the person's face? Because that's not quite the same thing as a crude/vulgar expression.

Comment: I realize this question is 8 years old, but under current standards, it requires a sample sentence showing how the word should be used, and without it is so broad as to be opinion-based.

Comment: I would say that person is "in need", but as with all provided responses, it is only circumstantially true.

Comment: Shiela? At least in Australia, and anywhere else if it’s her name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hormonal**

*You seem a little hormonal this week. Why don't you pour a glass of red and run a bath?*

You convey that your partner is 'acting up' but acknowledging it is neither person's fault — biology is biology after all and can't be helped.

Comment: That's a good suggestion! I don't think I would take offense, obviously the tone of voice is ultra important.

Comment: Would be more than my life is worth.

Comment: If I described my partner as "hormonal" to her face I'm pretty sure we would both be in for a very miserable night.

Comment: The flip side of saying 'it isn't your fault' is that you are saying 'you have no control over your actions' or even 'your opinion/commentary is invalid'. It really depends on the situation - if the person being referenced has accepted they have behaved in a way they wouldn't have, it shouldn't be offensive. If you are using it as a way to brush off the way their thoughts/actions, I would see it as offensive.

Comment: Not dv, but imho, the answer trades crudeness for a composed form of paternalistic condescenscion (take your _Lafite_ (still a chill pill) and wash yourself); I guess it depends on tone. I also find it technically imprecise and obfuscating as the hormonal peak should be [ovulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_cycle). As it stands _hormonal_ could apply to a body builder, to a man or a woman at andropause/menopause, or even to a fetus.

Comment: @Amphiteóth if said tongue-in-cheek and by a partner who is, after all, the person who knows you best, it isn't objectionable. Said by a total stranger then I'd consider it possibly rude or insensitive.

Answer (score 40):

Bearing in mind your specific request for non-vulgar terms, and being concerned with my own health and safety, the most commonly used words I use to address my better half when she is in such a state would be

> honey
>   dearest
>   baby
>   princess
>   sweetheart
>   buttercup
>   pumpkin
>   cupcake
>   darling

This is one of the rules to be found in the [*Handbook for the Married Man*](http://www.cutorcopy.com/wp-content/uploads/albums/260472197348116_61813/the-book-understanding-women-has-finally-arrived.jpg), the invaluable standard work that is traditionally only handed to men *after* they get married. It is the same work that advises against honest answers to questions that start with *does this  ...*, and explains the possible meanings of *nothing* in response to “what's the matter?”. The latter is a chapter that many of us men never get to fully comprehend, though.

Comment: LOL! LOL! LOL! Oh, thank you! I'm drying my *tears* of mirth and delight.

Comment: Your answer was a delight, *but* it didn't contain the language vocabulary I was looking for. On the bright side, I knew you'd be getting the populist gold badge. So congratulations!

Comment: A nice answer, but hardly appropriate to this question on ELU.

Answer (score 22):

"Grumpy." I do not ever call my wife a bitch, or even say that the is acting like one. I would definitely not call her bitchy. I might, while using one of oerkelens' terms of endearment, tell her, "You seem grumpy." If that does not express the idea accurately, I might say "especially grumpy."

Answer (score 14):

*out-of-sorts* is both accurate and not gender-specific. I think what gets up my nose the most is the assumption that my mood must necessarily mirror my hormone levels. Most times my mood is proportional to the amount of assitude in the air. ;)

Answer (score 9):

*Is there a word or expression for your partner or girlfriend or her behaviour?
What do you call a woman who's feeling "bitchy"?*

Why look for a word for a **woman** who acts that way or feels that way?  Isn't what you want a word for that behavior or that feeling? What is the point of trying to see behind the behavior or feeling to biology?

Sure, biology underlies the feelings and behavior of all of us - all of our feelings and all of our behavior - but in complex ways. Even "simple" hormones are extremely complex critters doing complex things. And individuals and their bodies and behavior vary tremendously.

The question smacks of asking about people of African ancestry being specially good at athletics or music.  We really don't need this simplistic kind of stereotyping anymore.

**But is my answer an answer to the question and not just a comment?** I think so - here is my answer:

Rephrase your question to *ask for words that describe the* ***particular behavior or feeling*** *that you have in mind* (even that will not be so easy to describe clearly, I think you'll find out). Forget about trying to bring women and ovulation cycles into the question - that's not helpful, IMHO.

You will anyway note, I think, that the most helpful answers so far describe the behavior or feeling, and have nothing to do with women in particular.

Just one opinion...

Comment: The question also says: *It's that time of the month...* And PMS is a reality, not for all women but that doesn't mean it's some type of urban myth. For some the symptoms may last only a day or two, for others it can last up a week. Some women are more fortunate and never experience any change in their moods. Nevertheless I appreciate your honesty, and I respect your opinion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Whatever the cause(s) of the behavior/feelings, I think the reasonable question is about characterizing the latter, not linking it to causes. No one has denied the reality of PMS. If you are grouchy, bitchy,... because of your ovulation cycle - alone or in combination with other factors, and if I act/feel similarly for different reasons, it is the behavior/feelings that count. How can describing behavior/feelings necessarily implicate a particular cause? I don't think such symptoms reflect accurately a single such influence. And if they do, I'm unaware of a word that captures that.

Comment: I think most of the answers given apply equally to men having their period. So I don't see any gender based stereotyping.

Comment: @oerkelens AFAIK men don't menstruate. What are you talking about re: men and periods?

Comment: @andy256: I disagree. See above: *But is my answer an answer to the question and not just a comment? I think so - here is my answer:*. That's my answer, and I'm sticking to it. It is the best way this question can be answered: *Ask for words that describe the particular behavior or feeling that you have in mind.*

Comment: Asserting that it's answer doesn't make it so :-)

Answer (score 8):

I wonder if the OP wanted a word to describe this female partner, rather than a term of endearment to placate them?

I think a great word to describe somebody who is being unreasonable because of the way they are feeling is "**Prickly**."

Google defines [prickly](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=prickly) as "ready to take offence" which seems to fit quite well.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't menstruation specific or even gender specific, but the term we use is either "cranky" or the slightly more humorous "cranky-pants". It's a non-inflammatory way of either asking or stating that there's something bothering you/them which isn't related to the other party and allows for comedic exchanges.

> "I think you really need to change your pants."
>   "What? Why?"
>   "You clearly have a crank in them."

Answer (score 7):

I use "[**grouchy**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grouchy)", meaning ill-tempered. My partner never objected to it, and she sometimes uses the term herself

From Dictionary.com:

> 1. sullenly discontented; sulky; morose; ill-tempered.

Answer (score 1):

A look at this posting titled ***[Most-hated pet names for female partners revealed](https://uk.style.yahoo.com/couples-pet-names-relationships-best-worst.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cDovL3d3dy53b3Jkd2l6YXJkLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAACe842xv-dhdmrgQnRwZTsP6PAnq5I9FdOxRabh-PMII2GfcJ0KIO-B9c1LiikFViI2_2X75WklNoKmL5tGxio_ZHNd_xJptasUlSkgJWWp4lcBcgLz594fKL76mA3P1ioB88wPUZoPSFWoeqO1JqQNYIAKxbO3XRo2eSNYjLr-h)*** (also discussed at [Wordwizard.com](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=23926)) should prove instructive regarding both the most desired and most undesired ways to address one's female beloved (if one is fortunate enough still to have one).

> ### 20 most hated
>
> 1. Babe
> 2. Sweet cheeks
> 3. Snookums
> 4. Baby doll
> 5. Baby girl
> 6. Muffin
> 7. Ducky
> 8. Baby cakes
> 9. Sexy pants
> 10. Pudding
> 11. Muffin
> 12. Angel pie
> 13. Pumpkin
> 14. Puppy
> 15. Sugar lips
> 16. Treacle
> 17. Baby
> 18. Pickle
> 19. Honeybun
> 20. Sugar pie
>
> ### 20 most acceptable
>
> 1. Gorgeous
> 2. Beautiful
> 3. Lovely
> 4. Love
> 5. Darling
> 6. Honey
> 7. Sexy
> 8. Angel
> 9. Dearest
> 10. Precious
> 11. Treasure
> 12. Snowflake
> 13. Blossom
> 14. Sweetie Pie
> 15. Sexy legs
> 16. Lover
> 17. Buttercup
> 18. Flower
> 19. Princess
> 20. Sweetness

Consult — and adopt/adapt — at your own risk. (I notice some unfortunate conflicts with Oerkelens' list of the words that he uses with his own — um — *better half*.)

Comment: Possibly *pumpkin* especially if she's sensitive about her weight. :P

Comment: Somehow, now, I feel like working late tonight... very late.

Comment: @oerkelens - In extreme cases, it may be wise to follow the maxim "Better never than late".

Answer (score 1):

Well, literally the noun associated with 'bitchy' would be 'bitch'. But I don't think either will do anything other than exacerbate the situation.

So fluffy wuffly snuggle snookums or some other disgustingly nauseatingly cute name that causes her to crack a smirk with how ludicrous it is.

Either that or 'grumpy ratbag'.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are describing is actually, **premenstrual**.

Comment: Probably the down-voter was saying *premenstrual* wouldn't be a term used by a partner,  or perhaps they object to labelling or describing a woman according to her cycle. I don't consider it a bad answer as such, and it's neither vulgar nor coarse. +1 from me.